# Accessing correct id in JSX for loop

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, react-native

I have the following code in React Native:

```
render() {
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    rows.push(
      <TouchableOpacity 
        key={i} 
        onPress={() => console.log(i)}>
        <Text>{i}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  return <View>{rows}</View>;
}
```

Which renders the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

However, when I one of the TouchableOpacity elements, the expectation is that pressing 3 will log `3` to the console. Instead, it logs `5` to the console. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables with `var` in JavaScript means they are globally scoped, versus block scoped like with `const` and `let`. So at the end of the `for` loop, `i` is 5 and each press will return 5. If you change your loop to use `let i`, it will resolve the problem.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  rows.push(
    <TouchableOpacity 
      key={i} 
      onPress={() => console.log(i)}>
      <Text>{i}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

See [this post](https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/) for further explanation on the above.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the value of `i` is 5 by the time `console.log` gets called.

An easy way to fix this is to not use a `for` loop, but just an array of integers, and `map`.

```
const rows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((i) => (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    key={i} 
    onPress={() => console.log(i)}>
    <Text>{i}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
));
```

If you do want to use a `for` loop, another easy fix is to refactor out the bits to create a `TouchableOpacity` to a function, so it has a local binding to the `i` name:

```
function makeThingamajig(i) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={i} onPress={() => console.log(i)}>
            <Text>{i}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    rows.push(makeThingamajig(i));
}
```